# bootstrap popover hides when hovering over popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to create popover with links. I am using the following code.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Default tooltip" title="popover content" data-html="true">Tooltip</a>
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ trigger: "hover" });
```

Popover is working fine but if hover on the popover it is closing. Can anyone give solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Default tooltip" title="popover content" data-html="true">Tooltip</a>


$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ trigger: "focus" });
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that it closes because you are out of your hover control (mouseleave). As a solution you might use a {trigger: "click"} or write your custom trigger the way you want it to be working.